# JS: remove lastChild only works every second button click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild

I use this code to delete the last item of an `<ul>` list, but only on the second, fourth, sixth, ... every second click on the button the item gets removed, but every click the message appears. What can I do that the element gets deleted on every click.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick = function () {
    'use strict';
    var list = document.getElementById('list'), item = list.lastChild;
    list.removeChild(item);
    window.alert("Removed");
};
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li id="child">List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Delete last">
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `.lastChild` returns all nodes, including empty text nodes which exist in your `<ul>`. Use `.lastElementChild` instead to target your `<li>` nodes

> The difference between this property and lastElementChild, is that
>   lastChild returns the last child node as an element node, a text node
>   or a comment node (depending on which one's last), while
>   lastElementChild returns the last child node as an element node
>   (ignores text and comment nodes).

See [HTML DOM lastChild Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp) and [HTML DOM lastElementChild Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_lastelementchild.asp) for more information

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick = function () {
    var list = document.getElementById('list'), item = list.lastElementChild;
    list.removeChild(item);
};
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li id="child">List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Delete last">
```

Some more details on why this is happening... When you format your markup with clean spacing, what I think of as "phantom" text nodes silently exist within your `<ul>`. If you minify this markup to the following, your first example would indeed work fine

```
<ul id="list"><li>List item 1</li><li>List item 2</li><li>List item 3</li><li id="child">List item 4</li><li>List item 5</li></ul>
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/yJiQAvyUIxoGeAIDdP9s?p=preview) - minifed markup example using `.lastChild`

Comment: Ok, it works now, I thought the text node is a child node of the element node, so removing the element node also removes the text node.

Comment: @danielr1996 which it does, but you were removing the `text node` not the `element node` using `lastElementChild` does remove the `element node` which also removes the `text node`

Comment: @danielr1996 it's weird, there are what I consider "phantom" text nodes in your `<ul>`. Check out [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6aaN2Cq7JAJiJWvOpaff?p=preview) to see the empty text nodes logged out to the console

Comment: @danielr1996 I added some additional detail to the answer that may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
item = list.lastChild;
```

to

```
item = list.lastElementChild;
```